# Is the word "以后" in "回家以后" an adverb?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

My question is as titled. Per my understanding the "以后" in "回家以后", "从此以后", etc. is a preposition. So I am surprised the textbook says 以后 is an adverb here. Can anyone find a grammar book, dictionary, or any kind of documents to prove the textbook is correct?

Comment: I think your textbook is wrong. No way this could be an adverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find a resource to cite from, but here's what I know.

In some grammar textbooks, whether Chinese or English, words like this are referred to as a [**Prepositional Adverb**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepositional_adverb), or words that are *very similar in its form to a preposition but functions as an adverb*.

---

**EDIT**

I am not certain about this, but some say that 以後（后） is one of the **post-positions**, which corresponds to prepositions in English.

---

Consider 以後/after in the following sentences:

- 以後(after) as a preposition.

> 好了以後，記得打給我。
>
> Call me after(when) you're done.

- "After" as an adverb.

> I will arrive soon after.
>
> 我馬上到。

- 以後 as an adverb. (?)

> 以後，我會再打給你。
>
> In the future, I will call you again.

Comment: for references to ＂prepositional adverb＂ may search Internet （i。p。note first ２ results）， it seems answer＃１ confirms that in the title example 以后 functions as ＂post－position＂ （corresponding to preposition in English， not as prepositional adverb which still is just a particular type of adverb, for examples in European languages see Internet）

Comment: Some users may feel that "adverb"（副词） in answer #1 would usually be called "adverbial" or "adverbial adjunct" (状语）and ＂以后＂ is a locality phrase （方位词组），which is used as adverbial。

Answer (score 2):

Chinese has a number of **post-positions （后置介词）**, instead of pre-position in English. But I have not seen an expert using this term.

A preposition or post-position （介词） is a word that requests a noun （介词宾语） to form a phrase （介词短语）. This **phrase** could be used as an adverb （介词短语作状语）.

For example,

(1) 他们是**工厂的**工人. They are workers **of the factory**.

(2) **桌子上**有一本书. There is a book **on the table**.

In English, for the phrase "of the factory", "of" is positioned before "the factory"; therefore, it is called a preposition.

In Chinese, for the phrase "工厂的", "的" is positioned after "工厂"; therefore, it should be, I think, called a post-position.

In your question, for the phrase "回家以后", "回家" is a noun, which is formed from the verb "回" and its object "家". "以后" is a post-position. It is not an adverb here because it requests the noun "回家".

"以后” can be used as an adverb by itself. For example, 我**以后**会还给你钱. I will give you money back **later**.

There is another example in which "然后" is used as a conjunction to connect two sentences:

> 我回家，然后会给你打电话。

These are just my two cents.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think "after returning home" is an [adverb phrase](http://www.taiwantestcentral.com/Grammar/Title.aspx?ID=115). "After" is the preposition as you said.

Comment: The link is about adverb phrase in English. Though there's similarity with 状语 in Chinese but there are a lot of differences and the two concepts should not be confused.